# Does Apache2::RequestUtil::pnotes shared variables between different requests?

Tags: perl

[The document](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestUtil.html#C_pnotes_) says :

> Share Perl variables between Perl HTTP handlers

Does it mean it shared variables between different requests?

Or only shares variables within ONE request?

Answer (score 0):

The latter - the data is made available to all handlers involved in generating a response to a single request and then the data is discarded.